# Give different URL's to different ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that give an URL value to the image when ID is found, so when is clicked goes to the specified URL:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("ww-enTeam").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      window.location = "/site/contact/#workwithus";
    }
document.getElementById("ww-enTeam").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

</script>
```

This works fine for a unique image. Now I have 3 images in 3 different languages, so I have to change the window.location to a different URL when clicked. And I can't find an example showing how does it work when you have 3 different IDs.

This is a tweak of a Wordpress lightbox plugin, website also uses Polylang, since I can't modify the code I have to resolve it this way.

Help always appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the URL reference in dynamically.

```
  document.getElementById("ww-enTeam").addEventListener("click", 
        myFunction('www.test.com/');

document.getElementById("anotherID").addEventListener("click", 
        myFunction('www.test2.com/');

        function myFunction(url) {
          window.location = url;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the id and url in a object where the ids are the ids of the image elements and the urls are their respective urls. And then write the function as:

```
let obj = {
    id1:url1, 
    id2:url2, 
    id3:url3
} 
function myFunction(evt) {
    window.location = obj[evt.target.id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a whole conclusion, I´d suggest the following:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event) {

    let els = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

        let id = els[i].id;
        let image = document.getElementById(id);

        image.addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.location = obj[id];
        });

    }

    let obj = {
        "id1": "http://myurl1.com", 
        "id2":"http://myurl2.com", 
        "id3":"http://myurl3.com"
    } 
});
```